# check if Integer is Null or numeric in groovy?

Tags: groovy, numbers, integer

I have a service method and have to throw an error if method parameter is null/blank or not numeric.

Caller is sending an Integer value but in called method how to check if it is numeric or null.

ex:

```
def add(value1,value2){
 //have to check value1 is null/blank
 //check value1 is numeric

}

caller: class.add(10,20)
```

Any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

More concrete that the [answer of Dan Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486292/462015), you can use [`String.isInteger()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isInteger%28%29) method:

```
def isValidInteger(value) {
    value.toString().isInteger()
}

assert !isValidInteger(null)
assert !isValidInteger('')
assert !isValidInteger(1.7)
assert isValidInteger(10)
```

But what happens if we pass a `String` that looks like a `Integer` for our method:

```
assert !isValidInteger('10')  // FAILS
```

I think that the most simple solution is use the `instanceof` operator, all assert are valid:

```
def isValidInteger(value) {
    value instanceof Integer
}
```

Comment: its nice example, but assert isValidInteger('10') should be right, b'z they may send Integer in String object, in that case  value instanceof Integer will not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could always define the types of your parameters:

```
Number add( Number value1, Number value2 ) {
  value1?.plus( value2 ?: 0 ) ?: value2 ?: 0
}

int a = 3
Integer b = 4
assert add(    a, null ) == 3
assert add( null,    3 ) == 3
assert add( null, null ) == 0
assert add(    a,    b ) == 7
assert add(    a,    4 ) == 7
assert add(    0,    a ) == 3
assert add(    1,    1 ) == 2
assert add(    0,    0 ) == 0
assert add(   -1,    2 ) == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Groovy's [`String.isNumber()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isNumber%28%29) method.

For example:

```
if (value1.isNumber()) ...
if (value2.isNumber()) ...
```

Comment: but I'm getting int value, i can't do it on int value.

Comment: Groovy does not use primitive types; did you mean `Integer`? You could use `if (!value1 || !value1.toString().isNumber()) ... else ...`. See [Groovy Truth](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Truth) for more info regarding `true`/`false` evaluations in Groovy.

Comment: Thanks Dan, !value1.toString().isNumber()) is did the trick..yes..was referring to Integer only.